# Issues with finding SQL records for current week and last week

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, strtotime

I've been having issues with this for about a month now. I built a copywriting management system for my company to help mitigate the strain of managing such a large project. The system pays the writers per item completed per week. Due to payroll restrictions, their pay period is from 12:00 am Thursday until 11:59 am Wednesday. On the writers' dashboard I have their totals displayed for last week's pay period and then the current amount they have written for this week.

I am doing this using strtotime() like so:

```
$currentdate = date("Y-m-d");
$lastweekstart = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2 thursdays ago'));
$lastweekend = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last wednesday'));
$thisweekstart = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last thursday'));
```

Then I retrieve the records from the database like this for last week:

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username='$username' AND date BETWEEN '$lastweekstart' AND '$lastweekend'");
```

and the current week:

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username='$username' AND date BETWEEN '$thisweekstart' AND '$date'");
```

This works great most of the week but on Thursdays it got a little crazy. So I started trying to change the $thisweekstart and $lastweekstart dates which worked until Friday and then it got nuts again. So, basically, below is my current code that does work on everyday except Fridays.

```
$lastweekstart = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2 thursdays ago'));
$lastweekend = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last wednesday'));
$thisweekstart = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last thursday'));
if ($date == date('Y-m-d', strtotime('thursday'))) {
    $thisweekstart = $date;
    $lastweekstart = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last thursday'));
} else {
    if ($date == date('Y-m-d', strtotime('friday'))) {
        $lastweekstart = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")-8,date("Y")));  
    }
}

// counts descriptions written last week
$lastcount = 0;
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username='$username' AND date BETWEEN '$lastweekstart' AND '$lastweekend'");
$lastcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

// counts descriptions written this week
if ($thisweekstart == $date) {
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username='$username' AND date='$date'");
} else {
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username='$username' AND date BETWEEN '$thisweekstart' AND '$date'");
}
$thiscount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

I'm still very new at PHP and my brain is fried on this issue. I need a fresh look. What do you guys (and gals) think? Is there a better way to go about weeks rather than using strtotime()?

Comment: much better ways than using str time look up mysql's DATE_SUB() function so you can do something useful like `select * from tbl where Date>=DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND Date<=NOW()`  Brief example but it'll save you all of those lines of code and you can do it in just the 2 alternate sql queries.

Comment: It goes crazy? what happens exactly

Comment: @Dave Very nice answer! I never tried to do operations date with DATE_SUB Mysql, is very usefull!

Comment: @Dave my date column in my sql table is set as varchar(16) with a format of YYYY-MM-DD. Should I change this to a date type and convert all the current dates to something more standard?

Comment: When storing a date/time stamp always use the datetime or timestamp formats in the db storing dates as strings causes you a nightmare of problems with comparisons as you're just string comparing then which even though visually to use the strings may be a start of week and end of week date in computer terms they wont be due to string sorting differences.  Using the correct data type will allow you to do much faster and more accurate date sorting etc

Comment: @BhavikShah It basically just provides the wrong numbers. It adds two weeks at a time for the "$lastcount" and always shows 0 for "$thiscount"

Comment: @Dave That makes sense. When teaching yourself this stuff, it's hard to figure out best practices until you do it wrong. I'll start working on switching it over - thanks!

Comment: I've put some example code below for you hopefully make a little more sense for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll put this here as I can use the code tags better and have more space.

So what we want to do is do 2 queries off a db where the first query runs last monday to last sunday and the 2nd query does this monday to next sunday

So first things first we need to find this previous sundays date and this mondays date

```
$lastsunday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last sunday'));
$thismonday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('this monday'));
//there's better ways of doing this probably but I'm just copy and pasting from your code above
```

Now we need to create our 2 sql queries

```
$last_week_sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE DateColumn>=DATE_SUB('$lastsunday',INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND DateColumn<='$lastsunday'";

$this_week_sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE DateColumn>='$thismonday' AND DateColumn<=DATE_ADD('$thismonday',INTERVAL 7 DAY)";
```

Now you'll notice I'm using >= <= and NOT `BETWEEN()`.  This is because BETWEEN is explicitly that it ignores the start and end points so if you had numbers `BETWEEN(1,10)` it would only match against 2 -> 9 and ignore 1 and 10.  It does the same with dates. Use it with caution!

Also note when injecting the date string variable directly its wrapped in single quotes ' this is because mysql treats date inputs as strings.

Comment: So that means that I *can* change my column type for my date column to "date" and it won't harm anything. I'll get this implemented on the dev server asap

Comment: @deepfryerdan shouldn't do as long as all the dates in the data are in the correct mysql format of yyyy-mm-dd at least for a date type column or with added time stamp if they're datetime.  Personally I always use datetime format for the columns and set the time portion to one minute after midnight if its not needed but I think thats just my personal way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use MySQL for this kind of functionality (When DB serves you with this kind of functionality- use it)

Read up on  ***date and time functions*** in MySQL. Here's a list of functions and examples
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

This is just a starting-point. I think in your case it would be enough using CUR_DATE(), DATE_SUB() AND INTERVAL directly in your SQL-statement(s).

Your column where your store dates should be of any of these types: ***date, datetime or datestamp:***
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html